# pandas how to finds missing matching column values when merging two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When matching two `df`s (say `A` and `B`) on values of a column called `id_number`, I am trying to identify rows in `A`, which cannot find a matching id number in `B`, e.g. `A` is like,

```
id_number    name
1            a
2            b
3            c
```

`B` is like,

```
id_number    year
1            2007
2            2010
4            2008
```

I want to create a boolean column called `has_b` in `A`, result in,

```
id_number    name    has_b
1            a       True
2            b       True
3            c       False
```

I am wondering how to achieve the above dataframe.

Comment: `A['has_B'] = A.id_number.isin(B.id_number)`?